# Efficient SQL query or index to find if all of a column has only 1 value

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, triggers, database-performance

I have a MySQL database with an `items` table, and each item is scoped to an account.
Those items can each have one of a handful of colors, something like this:

**items**

```
id | account_id | color
------------------------
1  | 1          | white
2  | 1          | white
3  | 1          | blue
4  | 1          | red
5  | 2          | white
6  | 2          | white
7  | 2          | white
```

On a display page for an item, we want to show the color of the item, but **only if an account has ever used more than one color**. Once they start to use another color in that account, we want to show colors for all the items.

For example:

- When displaying the item with ID of `1`, we'd show that is it is
  `white`, because the account has items that are a mix of white, blue
  and red.
- When displaying the item with ID of `7`, we'd not show the color,
  because all colors in the account are the same (white), so there is
  no need to use color to distinguish them.

To make this check, I’m currently picking any item in the account (the first, but it could be any), and running a query to see if there are any in the account that don’t have the same color, like this:

```sql
// Get any color in the account:
SELECT color FROM items WHERE account_id = 1 LIMIT 1;

// See if any other color is used ("red" was returned from the previous query):
SELECT 1 AS one FROM `items` WHERE account_id = 1 AND color != 'red' LIMIT 1;
```

This works, and is fairly efficient for accounts that have a bunch of colors they cycle through, but some accounts could have thousands or millions of items, and may only use one color, so it might have to scan every row in an account to see if there are none that are different.

I've already tried adding a composite index on `account_id` and `color`, but even that index would have to scan thousands or millions of records to be sure, since there are only a handful of colors to group into.

Is this acceptable? Is there a special kind of index I could use that would be efficient here, or would I need to add a trigger/procedure to update a cached column or table on every insert?

What I mean about triggers is something like this:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER items_after_insert_update_account_colors
AFTER INSERT
ON items FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  // Insert row, but ignore if the exact row already exists.
  INSERT IGNORE INTO account_colors
  SET color = NEW.color, account_id = NEW.account_id; 
END$$

DELIMITER;
```

Then checking that table to determine whether to show the color or not with a query like this:

```sql
// True if other color is found for account.
SELECT 1 AS one FROM account_colors WHERE account_id = 1 AND color != 'red' LIMIT 1;
```

Is there an index technique I can use to do this efficiently, or is using a trigger like above to cache the current state of the table, and update it on every insert, the best I can do?

To summarize, I guess I'm asking if there's a way to make an index work like the above, where even for millions of records, the index is tiny and only needs to hold the minimum info like this:

```
account_id | uses_color
-----------------------
1          | white
1          | blue
1          | red
2          | white
```

or

```
account_id | used_colors
-------------------------------------
1          | ['blue', 'white', 'red']
2          | ['white']
```

Comment: What does a trigger have to do with this?  What results do you want from a query?

Comment: Luckily, this is true of all the accounts thus far provided

Comment: @GordonLinoff The trigger is just an example of how I might accomplish this if there isn't a good index strategy that is fast for millions of rows. I want a query to tell me if there's only one color used in the entire account quickly.

Comment: Please provide example data for the various use cases, and show the desired output.

Comment: @RickJames I've added some more columns to the example to show an account with all matching colors, and explained my desired result. Thanks for letting me know where I was less than clear.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest `exists`:

```
select i.*
from items i
where exists (select 1
              from items i2
              where i2.account_id = i.account_id and
                    i2.color <> i.color
             )
order by i2.account_id;
```

Then for performance you want an index on `items(account_id, color)`.

Comment: Thank you for showing how I could accomplish this in one query, but that's not my goal here. I've already added this index, and while it does perform better, it's still slower than I'd like. I'm looking for an compact index technique that maybe works like the trigger, I've updated the question with more details and examples.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(col)) FROM table;
```

will return 1 if there is only one different value in that column.

A `WHERE` clause can be tacked onto it to limit it in some way.  And you could use the result in a subquery.

Comment: Wouldn't `COUNT(DISTINCT(col))` be much slower than `COUNT(col) > 1` or `WHERE col != 'value' LIMIT 1`? I have solutions that work already, I just want to know if there's something fast for millions of rows.

Comment: @Unixmonkey - Do you know the one "value"?  It would be slower to first fetch the "value".  In your first example, `COUNT(DISTINCT value)` is 3 for acct 1; and is 1 for acct 2.  `COUNT(value)` is `>1` for each acct.